# WIF: Determining whether a user has a valid session with the STS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

In a Windows Identity Foundation based SSO implementation, is there a way of determining whether a user  has a valid session with the STS, from a default unprotected page in one of the relying parties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for claims - to have valid claims, the user must have a valid session.

Or use:

httpContextBase.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

IsAuthenticated implies a token exists (which only occurs when the user is signed in).